# Taharah and istinjaa and urinate

Tags: taharah

It is mandatory to wash testicles after urine or just put water on penis suffice the job.because urine does not come to my testicle

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wash your testicles because the urine doesn't reach there. But if urine gets on your testicles you have clean using water three times. If there is no urine on the testicles you should clean your penis using tissue or other materials and then use the water.

Jazakallah Khairan

Comment: It is necessary to use tissue can we just simply pour water on private part

Comment: It is a Sunnah of prophet (PBUH)